# Border or table inside of a table, rows, cells?

Tags: html, .net-core

I want to put a table or border for the inside contents in the foreach loop and I'm not sure how to do it.

I have tried a cell and row inside of the Item.Description and I know that doesn't work.

```
<div id="printContainer" class="col-md-12">
    <partial name="_CardDetails" model="@Model.Current" />
    <div class="verticalspace"></div>
    <div class="verticalspace"></div>
    <div class="verticalspace"></div>
    <table id="itemsTable" class="table table-bordered display responsive nowrap" style="width: 100%">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ToView.Items ?? Enumerable.Empty<Item>())
            {
                <tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #f9f9f9">
                    <td colspan="4"><b>@Item.Category.Name</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>@Html.Raw(Item.Responsibility)</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left">
                        <b>@Html.Raw(Item.Description)</b>

                        @foreach (var response in Model.Responses)
                        {
                            <br />
                            <br />

                            <b>@Html.Raw(response.DateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) 
                            @Html.Raw(response.Title)</b>
                            <br />
                            @Html.Raw(response.Response)
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td><b>@item.Status.Name</b></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

I expect that the foreach loop to have its own border around it.

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS style

```css
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="printContainer" class="col-md-12">

            <partial name="_CardDetails" model="@Model.Current" />
            <div class="verticalspace"></div>
            <div class="verticalspace"></div>
            <div class="verticalspace"></div>
            <table id="itemsTable" class="table   table-bordered display 
              responsive nowrap" style="width: 100%">
                
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ToView.Items ?? 
              Enumerable.Empty<Item>())
                    {
                        <tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #f9f9f9"><td 
               colspan="4"><b>@Item.Category.Name</b></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>@Html.Raw(Item.Responsibility)</b> 
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left">
                                <b>@Html.Raw(Item.Description)</b>

                                @foreach (var response in 
                       Model.Responses)
                                {
                                    <br />
                                    <br />

            <b>@Html.Raw(response.DateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) 
                @Html.Raw(response.Title)</b>
                                    <br />
                                    @Html.Raw(response.Response)
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td><b>@item.Status.Name</b></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                  
              </table>
           </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I need. I want to put a border from the foreach loop. Not from the <td style="text-align: left">
                                <b>@Html.Raw(Item.Description)</b>. Does that make sense?

Comment: you can put <div> tag and set it border

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly check this code. You can use "border" properties in the css for each of column in body.

```css
table {
  width: 320px;
}

tr td {
  width: 50%;
}

thead td {
  background: #333;
}

tbody tr td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a class in css for each desired element you want to have border. If you want every cell to have border and looks like a table you can reference the td elements inside the table. 
Something like the following:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can play around with the css code to get the desired style.

You could also only apply it to tr elements if that is the look and feel you want to have. It is just a matter of trying different things and applying the border instructions to the elements you want.

```
table, tr {
   border: 1px solid green;
}
```